# how to set and get new data in angulajs

Tags: angularjs

when adding products and price it was added in the table. how to set the added data and get the data in another view

```
routerApp.controller('products', function ($scope) {

    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.addRow = function() {    
        $scope.items.push({'Products': $scope.Products,'Price':$scope.Price});
    }
```

Comment: You can use $route or just create a global js variable and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically for data sharing in different view we are using factory and services. Because they are singleton object. [Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763696/how-to-pass-array-from-service-function-to-scope-in-controller-angularjs/29764590#29764590) for same

```
app.factory('authUser', function() {
var userAcl = {
    user_id: 1,
    user: {} // can be anything
};
return {
    getUserAcl: function() {
        return userAcl;
    },
    setUserAcl: function(user) {
        userAcl = user;
    }
}
```

});

Inject factory as an dependency in controller or else where and use get/ set methods for sharing the data may be in different view.